# Can WP-CLI modify database connection details in an existing wp-config file?

Tags: wordpress, wp-cli

I am aware of WP-CLI's many database interaction functions via "[wp db](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/db/)" and its functions for *generating* wp-config files via "[wp config](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/config/)" - However I cannot find a way of using WP-CLI to modify existing database name, username and password settings in wp-config.

I am migrating multiple sites, and the ability to do this would be a time saver.

I am aware that wp config can launch vi editor (`wp config edit`), but I am looking for a way to pass the database name, username and password TO WP-CLI to have it do the job for me. Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wp config` subcommand can alter your `wp-config.php` file without trying to fire up the whole WordPress stack or open the database. So you could change, for example, your DB_HOST like so.

```
wp config set DB_HOST mariadb.example.com
```

It works for any `define()` in your config file.

It takes four of these `set` commands to modify host, database, user, and password, of course.

Comment: Fantastic, I had missed the "set" capability of the ```wp-config``` command - https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/config/set/ - Thanks!